# Suspected Problem with UTF8 in .bib file

Tags: unicode, biber

I've got the following problem. When I try to compile my .tex file I get:

> "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8 not set up for use with LaTeX".

The .tex file is UTF8 encoded.

Running biker on the bib file gives:

```
"INFO - This is Biber 1.6
INFO - Logfile is 'Seminararbeit Copulas.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Seminararbeit Copulas.bcf'
Entity: line 1850: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
    <bcf:field>"
```

Now this pretty much just showed up out of the blue. I added an entry to my BibTeX file and tried to cite it. I've since removed both the citation and the BibTeX entry but the error persists.

The problematic BibTeX entry is:

```
@article{aloui2011global,
  title={Global financial crisis, extreme interdependences, and contagion effects: The role of economic structure?},
  author={Aloui, Riadh and A{\"\i}ssa, Mohamed Safouane Ben and Nguyen, Duc Khuong},
  journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
  volume={35},
  number={1},
  pages={130--141},
  year={2011},
  publisher={North-Holland}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `.bib` file worked fine in a short test I conducted. Have you saved both the `.tex` and `.bib` file in UTF8 encoding, do you also have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the `.tex` file? Please prepare a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/). A MWE normally consist of a short `.tex` file with all the unnecessary packages omitted (you probably only need a `documentclass`, the call to `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `biblatex` here) as well as the `.bib` file (but please find out which entry causes the problem first and post only a short piece of that file).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I've created a MWE and cited every entry in the BibTeX file and it works. I've made sure that both the .tex file and the .bib file are UTF8 encoded and I do use the inputenc package with the utf8 option. So if the BibTeX file isn't the problem it must be something in my .tex file? However the line it points me to is the one after \printbibliography...

Comment: I have identified the culprit:

@article{aloui2011global,
  title={Global financial crisis, extreme interdependences, and contagion effects: The role of economic structure?},
  author={Aloui, Riadh and A{\"\i}ssa, Mohamed Safouane Ben and Nguyen, Duc Khuong},
  journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
  volume={35},
  number={1},
  pages={130--141},
  year={2011},
  publisher={North-Holland}
} I copied that over from google scholar. Everything seems properly escaped though..

Comment: Check for invisible characters. Especially if you copy-pasted rather than exporting and saving the entry from google, you may have picked up a control sequence you can't see. These can be very frustrating as everything looks right but you keep getting errors. If you cannot find it, try typing the entry out again by hand and deleting the original.

Comment: `A{\"\i}ssa` is too much of a good thing, I think, try `A{\"i}ssa` instead. (You might have to delete all your auxiliary `.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl` files. You will have to rerun Biber as well as LaTeX.) It might also be time to update Biber, version 1.6 is quite old (current version is 1.8; you need to update `biblatex` as well, the matching version is 2.8).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an input (encoding) problem with the `.bib` file.